# Expanding application.yml during Gradle processResources gives MissingPropertyException

Tags: gradle, spring-boot

To replaces properties in my Spring Boot `application.yml` I've added:

```
processResources {
    filesMatching("**/application.yml") {
        expand(project.properties)
    }
}
```

The replacement fails but gives a `MissingPropertyException`:

```
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST for class: SimpleTemplateScript1
        at SimpleTemplateScript1.run(SimpleTemplateScript1.groovy:49)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.FilterChain$3.transform(FilterChain.java:95)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.FilterChain$3.transform(FilterChain.java:84)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.ChainingTransformer.transform(ChainingTransformer.java:37)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.FilterChain.transform(FilterChain.java:39)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.FilterChain.transform(FilterChain.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.DefaultFileCopyDetails.open(DefaultFileCopyDetails.java:86)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileTreeElement.copyTo(AbstractFileTreeElement.java:56)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.DefaultFileCopyDetails.copyTo(DefaultFileCopyDetails.java:94)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileTreeElement.copyFile(AbstractFileTreeElement.java:93)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileTreeElement.copyTo(AbstractFileTreeElement.java:74)
        ... 81 more
```

Originally my `application.yml` contained:

```
url: jdbc:mysql://${OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST}:${OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT}/${OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME}
```

Note these Openshift variables are only know on Openshift production environment but not when running locally in dev mode.

As stated on http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy.html: `You can also include arbitrary Groovy code in the file, such as ${version ?: 'unknown'}` so I changed my `application.yml` to:

```
url: jdbc:mysql://${OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST ?: ''}:${OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT ?: ''}/${OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME ?: ''}
```

But this gives the same `MissingPropertyException`.
Am I missing something here?

Comment: If you run a `gradle properties` can you see those OPENSHIFT variables in the list?

Comment: No it is not. It's resolved runtime using Spring Boot property placeholders as documented here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-properties-and-configuration.html

Comment: I now also see the note in the docs that for the maven-resources-plugins the default placeholder `${*}` is changed to `@*@`. I wonder how this works for the gradle processresources. It seems to be Spring Boot related and not Gradle.

Comment: So probably the questions is how to change the delimiter when using Gradle expand.

Comment: Or how to ignore/escape ${ in resources by using something like \${

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The Gradle `expand` `${..}` style conflicts with the same Spring property placeholder style and therefor needs to be escaped like `\${..}`.
This is added to Spring Boot docs now: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/commit/c0c67f2593dbfd17aa304b43f4da3a3678fa58eb